# Loop variable is not updated inside function in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firestore's `documentSnapshot` function to check whether document exists or not.

I am running the function in a for loop till value 5.

Although, the function is running 5 times, as I could see in my console, but the value of 'i' is always the last value, not from the beginning that is (0,1,2,3,4..). Outside the function, the value of i is printed continuously.

```
user="manjoola";

  private saveToken(user, token): void {      
        var i:number=0;
        var user_document:string=user;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
      {
        user_document=user+i;
        console.log(user_document);
  this.firestore.doc(`pushnotifications/${user_document}`).ref.get().then((documentSnapshot) => {   

    console.log(documentSnapshot.exists);
    if(documentSnapshot.exists)
    {    

    console.log('It exists'+user+i);
    snapshot=true;    
      }

    else
    {
      this.firestore.collection(`pushnotifications`).doc(`${user_document}`).set({'authtoken': user, 'fcmtoken': token});
      console.log('Does not exists'+user+i);
      snapshot=false;

    }
    snapshot=false;
  }).catch(function (error)
  {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
  }
  ); 

  console.log(i);

}
}
```

Console output:

```
manjoola0
messaging.service.ts:137 0
messaging.service.ts:112 manjoola1
messaging.service.ts:137 1
messaging.service.ts:112 manjoola2
messaging.service.ts:137 2
messaging.service.ts:112 manjoola3
messaging.service.ts:137 3
messaging.service.ts:112 manjoola4
messaging.service.ts:137 4
messaging.service.ts:115 false
messaging.service.ts:126 Does not existsmanjoola5
messaging.service.ts:115 false
messaging.service.ts:126 Does not existsmanjoola5
messaging.service.ts:115 false
messaging.service.ts:126 Does not existsmanjoola5
messaging.service.ts:115 false
messaging.service.ts:126 Does not existsmanjoola5
messaging.service.ts:115 true
messaging.service.ts:119 It existsmanjoola5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this: `for(i=0;i<5;i++)`

to this: `for(let i=0; i<5; i++)`

The above would make the `i` variable block-scoped instead of function-scoped and should fix your problem.

In order for the above to work, remove this line, too: `var i:number=0;` - this is to prevent "variable has already been declared error" (you initialize `i` in the for statement)